# Make: Interrupt/Exception caught

Tags: gcc, build, linker, gnu-make, ld

<s>When a recipe in my makefile fails to compile because of a code error I am provided with an unhelpful message from make.</s>

```
>make debuglog.o
make: ***.  Stop.
```

When I manually invoke the commands which make would use, I am provided with a useful error message.

```
>gcc -std=c11 -Iinclude -c debuglog.c

debuglog.c: In function 'writeToLog':
debuglog.c:22:29: error: expected expression before '=' token
 ...
```

This doesn't happen with other recipes in the same makefile however sometimes after changing the code, `make` errors with `make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005 ...)`, but rerunning the recipe works fine and everything compiles/links. I'm not sure if the problems are related.

<s>I may have written my recipe incorrectly:</s>

```
debuglog.o : include/debuglog.h include/config.h debuglog.c
    $(CC) -std=c11 -Iinclude -c debuglog.c
```

I would expect any error messages generated by GCC to be displayed before make fails/terminates, but they aren't shown.

Platform: Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 [Version 6.1.7601]

```
>make -v
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-w64-mingw32

>gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3
```

---

**Edit**: I changed my toolchain and I now always get useful error messages (with color), however the Interrupt/Exception error now occurs every time I change `main.c`. All `.o` files are created, so I think the error must be occurring when linking. I can run `make` multiple times without error as long as re-compiling isn't required.

Perhaps I need to now update `make`, to prevent some sort of concurrency/file access issue...?

```
>gcc --version
gcc (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0

>ld -v
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.32
```

---

**Edit 2**: If I edit my `makefile` recipe thusly

```
app : debuglog.o minIni.o main.o
    C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sleep.exe 1
    $(LINK) -o app minIni.o debuglog.o main.o -Llib -lkernel32 -lole32 -Bstatic -lmingw32 -lgcc -Bdynamic -lglew32.dll -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lOpenGL32 -lfreetype -lavformat -lavdevice -lavcodec -lx264 -lavutil
```

I can call `make` multiple times and the error doesn't resolve itself!

```
>make
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sleep.exe 1
make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x000007FEFF7C2020)

>make
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sleep.exe 1
make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x000007FEFF7C2020)

>make
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sleep.exe 1
make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x000007FEFF7C2020)

...
```

But as soon as I remove the sleep line,

```
>make
gcc -o app minIni.o debuglog.o main.o -Llib -lkernel32 -lole32 -Bstatic -lmingw32 -lgcc -Bdynamic -lglew32.dll -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lOpenGL32 -lfreetype -lavformat -lavdevice -lavcodec -lx264 -lavutil

>
```

it works OK!?

Comment: I wouldn't expect them to be "passed through make".  I would expect gcc to inherit stderr from make and write the error messages directly to it.

Comment: Yeah I agree with that. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: It looks as if `make` did not even try to execute the rule. Maybe it crashed somehow. The error message looks strange and the exception message is also suspicious. This might be related: https://superuser.com/questions/375029/make-interrupt-exception-caught

Comment: I actually already have `SHELL=C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe` and that bug was apparently fixed in Make 3.82 (I use 4.0).
I tried reducing my path with `PATH=C:/winBuilds/bin;C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin;C:/Windows/system32;C:/Windows`, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Your rule for `debuglog.o` looks OK, except that the recipe seems to be indented with spaces.  That may very well be an artifact of posting it here, but do be aware that each line of the recipe should be indented specifically with (at least) an initial tab.

Comment: If that's not the issue (and I suspect it isn't) then we probably need a [mre] if we're to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Can you try and see how it behaves inside the mintty terminal, and with bash as the shell?